# Should I use a shared server for social networking app for my college?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I am developing an Android application for my college. There will be no more than 10000 users in total, and we can assume that no more than 500 concurrent users will be there at any given time.

They all will be posting their status, photos, making comments (except video sharing). I am using only MySQL as database (without memcache or some other technology) and PHP as web service.

I want to ask, will a shared server serve for my purpose? Because it will be a free app and the cost of dedicated server will be too high.

Comment: Are you really going to enlist 10,000 people?

Comment: I'd suggest to start with the cheapest (find a friend who has a shared hosting) and only **if** it happens to be too small then rent a server.

Comment: so initially shared hosting will be able to manage the traffic??

Comment: #Waleed Khan..didn't get u

Comment: @user2075703 We have no idea of the traffic. 500 concurrent users means very different things depending on what they do...

Comment: i already mentioned what they would be doing...posting their status, liking  the status, sharing pics and all stuff.

Comment: It's difficult to be specific - do some tests on a local machine with five volunteers, and then scale the estimates up. Shared hosting is good cost-wise, but you may outgrow it. Personally I would start off with a VPS, since capacity changes can be made in the time it takes to reboot - and starter/budget VPS deals are nearly the same price as shared hosting now.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give specific answer.

Hosting companies very often offer possibility to test their hosting for some time (e.g. 14 days). I think you should use this free period and do performance tests. Then you will know wheter it's enough for your neeeds.